# Hypnotoad Logfile

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Does Hypnotoad write any Logfile?
I can't find anything about that here: http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/Server/Hypnotoad
Also the option `--help` says nothing about it.

I understand, that application-wise I need to use stuff like `$self->app->log->error('aua!')`... but something like a server log does not exist? (e.g. client requests, internal errors, etc)

If the answer is just no, I'm fine.
This would then mean, that I would need to implement this in my application I guess.
I can imagine that it makes sense to keep server-code small and clean here, maybe this would be the reason for a lack of this functionality?
Or is it that I can enable it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your application has a `log` folder, the log will be written there: http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Tutorial#Mode

Comment: The linked page (http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Lite#Mode) doesn't confirm this fact, and I couldn't easily find any documentation of it, but in Mojolicious 6.03 it still works.  Also, the `log` directory belongs in the same directory as the main script, at least by default (I'm not sure if there is a way to change this).

Comment: Good catch. Yes the `Mojolicious::Lite` documentation also used to double as the tutorial. Since then we have split the documentation so that there is an actual tutorial guide. I have updated the link.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think so, but it's easy to set one up.

```
use Mojo::Log;
...
app->log( Mojo::Log->new( path => <filename>, level => 'debug' ) );
...
app->start;
```

Answer (score 3):

> app->log( Mojo::Log->new( path => , level => 'debug' ) );

Insert it to startup function